# Understanding the states, phaser game development framework

Tags: html, states, phaser-framework

I'm new in game development and I have some difficulties understanding the states in the phaser.io framework. So my questions are : 
- How does Phaser recognize a state? (Sometimes I think I've declared one, but while compiling 
an error message tell me that no, there is no state with the key: 'key')
- What is the most efficient way to work with states?
- And finally, there is any "good practices" can you share guys about this framework?

Thank you so much guys for your answers.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you showed some failing code. Specifically the code you're using to initialize the state and the code that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you got that error it's mean that there is something wrong in you state declaration. I usually start my code like this:

```
var game = Phaser.Game(800, 480, Phaser.AUTO, 'PhaserContainer');

game.state.add('phaser_state_key', {
  create: function() {
    console.log('create methode for phaser_state_key');
  }
});
```

Consider to read tutorial from link below if you want to know how to use this framework.

http://www.codevinsky.com/phaser-2-0-tutorial-flappy-bird-part-1/

http://www.gamedevacademy.org/html5-phaser-tutorial-top-down-games-with-tiled/